# What kind of service to get done on a car in its 4th year but having only 10k miles?

Tags: scheduled-maintenance

My car (2012 VW Passat SE) is in its 4th year but only has 10k miles on it. I am wondering if I need to get the 40k/4year service done on the car which is going to cost $700 (I think it includes a head to toe inspection plus oil and spark plug change) or if I could just get an oil change done. I don't know anything about cars so thought could ask here. Does a spark plug need to be replaced with age or miles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My best advice would be that you should get your car serviced regularly as per the manufacturers recommendation.

A 40k or 4 year service would normally mean that it needs that service at 40k miles or 4 years of age - ***whichever comes first***. What I mean by this is that if lets say your car had done 40k miles in one year, it would need a service due to the fact that it has traveled the 40k miles specified. Equally, having done only 10k in 4 years, you will still need a service due to the fact that you have reached that 4 year time interval.

This is due to the fact that certain components on your car are going to need replacing after a certain time interval, irrespective of how many miles have been put on the car in that time. Components that may wear out due to time include (but are not limited to) things like the rubber cam and serpentine belts, fuel and oil filters, engine oil and engine coolant. If these things are not replaced as and when they should be, they can lead to other issues with your car later on.

*Note:* I will add that usually cars tend to get a minor service once a year (unless you have a major service), and a major service every other year. You may want to see [this page on the Volkswagen website](http://www.volkswagen.co.uk/owners/servicing/regimes) for more information about the different types of service that you may want to consider for your Volkswagen.

Answer (score 3):

It is always recommend to get the vehicle serviced as per manufacturer specification. weather it is less kilometer or less time, It is because of the following reason.

1. If the vehicle exceed the manufacturer specific distance then automatically the engine oil, coolant, filters need to be monitored, if needed replace or top-up need to be done.
2. If the vehicle exceed the manufacturer specific time, then the rubber parts like belts, consumable part like filters, oils, coolant may get spoiled, so it need to be replaced.

---

So it is advisable to take your vehicle to the authorized service station and get the complete check-up.